# How to conditionally type a key depending on another key of same object

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have tried to create a type that changes depending on which enum's value is being used:

```js
enum StatusEnum {
  UPDATE = 'update',
  CREATE = 'create'
}

type LogKeyType<K extends StatusEnum> =
  K extends StatusEnum.UPDATE ? Record<string, any> : undefined

type Props = {
  status: StatusEnum
  log: LogKeyType<status> // <-- here is the key that should change type depending on status
  // other keys...
}
```

For this line : `log: LogKeyType<status>` I get an error saying that status refers as a value but is being used as a type and I did not manage to get pass this error.

I've then tried to to use generic type too :

```js
enum StatusEnum {
  UPDATE = 'update',
  CREATE = 'create'
}

type LogKeyType<K extends StatusEnum> =
  K extends StatusEnum.UPDATE ? Record<string, any> : undefined

type Props<K extends StatusEnum> = {
  status: K
  log: LogKeyType<K> 
  // other keys...
}
```

but typescript can't tell what's the type of `log`.

This is to be used in this use case :

```js
if (props.status === StatusEnum.UPDATE) {
  // do something with props.log that won't be undefined
}
```

I could also check directly if log is undefined or not but it wouldn't be as fancy.

EDIT:

Here is the error I'm talking about in my comment from Baka's answer : [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8BlGFGWgZwFE68BvcuOAFUACgBEAggBUOcALwFaYACYsk+ADT84AYQQcpM+fjRFV+cgF9KwajCRRM6JHABCKNkmE4wbOHwFszKxsAFxwTCzsXPQUAgD0cXAQMAAW9nAA1kgAnmwAdAVabLhI4lAARsAwUChQ2QDSOWGBUDYA5hRW5DZ2Dk5CyqpwSAAedtRKvm4eXhA+fkVB7GERwdEgeSIS0rFwADYQbWHIaNBKADwt7epwKNTZAHyd1rb2jmjO2qZ2w2M0k653J5vL5-HBApFQuElpxuHldPodpZKDBsmBnLN5vJBIMfgAfHTfJAUKgjSCwOCnaiBHS4SDUGgwY7EGB5ABi2nOmLYDzkcDAILkvLBeyQWGASD2kzCPGASma1WucCIE3sYQAFOqAJRCxAsvLIdAwDiikCM853bI3K7UNpwAmGjB5ABSDAAGiakGbbNoINTqrQMNALfcHg8dQTaKrMDYkEoLABtAC6fOTWmAmDg6oFc3yEOCclk8lWUThWwMOrBAipxVFeQObWzIPrhx1CTg1AgcFR6OGUBwUEoAgEMclAPko6l+SpaBY6qrw7lYXwaT2Bw0WmHyv+aqzOtkvPONjAtHgADcUHtaEhZDwcz4W208ilgBY4HFee2YL57AOktQ4BAbJwTlZwQk3Yd20kBgACYAGY4IATjCTF7FRAgG3wOAlAgJBfE7eBRmAGk-W7NFnHwABZJAxXaSiIBUPZJHI-A8gg+JEgEVDYGA-BMOw3D8OSX5iPgUiewor5UDsViIIsLUtC6AQiFYKAAPOJRgDPd8nmRIA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)

Here's an example of how you can use it with your enum:

```
import React from 'react';

enum StatusEnum {
  UPDATE = 'update',
  CREATE = 'create'
}

interface BaseProps {
  status: StatusEnum;
  // other keys...
  someArbitraryKey: string;
}

interface Update extends BaseProps {
  status: StatusEnum.UPDATE;
  log: Record<string, any>;
}

interface Create extends BaseProps {
  status: StatusEnum.CREATE;
}

type Props = Update | Create;

export const Component: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  if (props.status === StatusEnum.UPDATE) {
    return <div>{props.log}</div>; // no type error
  }

  if (props.someArbitraryKey.length) { // someArbitraryKey is always available
    return <div>{props.log}</div>; // error, undefined log
  }

  return <div />;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8BlGFGWgZwFE68BvcuOAFUACgBEAggBUOcALwFaYACYsk%20ADT84AYQQcpM%20fjRFV%20cgF9KwajCRRM6JHABCKNkmE4wbOHwFszKxsAFxwTCzsXPQUAgD0cXAQMAAW9nAA1kgAnmwAdAVabLhI4lAARsAwUChQ2QDSOWGBUDYA5hRW5DZ2Dk5CyqpwSAAedtRKvm4eXhA%20fkVB7GERwdEgeSIS0rFwADYQbWHIaNBKADwt7epwKNTZAHyd1rb2jmjO2qZ2w2M0k653J5vL5-HBApFQuElpxuHldPodpZKDBsmBnLN5vJBIMfgAfHTfJAUKgjSCwOCnaiBHS4SDUGgwY7EGB5ABi2nOmLYDzkcDAILkvLBwEwcAAFAK5vkIcE5LJ5KsonCtgYAJQLAQCIisKDUODnJTAABuDx4Up8eQObQs5ziRtNpDgCTg1AgcFR6OGUBwUC0XQEoolFplJTKlWqtQaOStNDaqQ1PGdiWKIFKFSqNTqjWycGAvhQewA7ihcrdjShgHsUOU9kgtNqkLr9YaTWaQ1bDrb7W2nS77L6brQJkhMDYkEp9od-ZRG82DQ7nU9kUA)

Comment: Good answer, It sould be good if you also add commented code directly in the answer (Of course keep the link to the TS Playground).

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I have an error on my side that I cannot reproduce in the TS playground, link is too long for the comment, I will edit my question.

Comment: @HartWoom `> Property 'log' does not exist on type 'Create'` — Are you sure you're comparing  `props.status` to correct enum value on your side? Also if you caught this error in your IDE/editor and enum value in `if` condition is correct, check `tsc` output, maybe it's just IDE or LSP plugin related issue

Comment: @Baka yup I'm sure about the if condition. The error is also in my console, tsc won't let me compile. But it's not really an issue, I just need to declare a const in the if brackets.